# Check if installed version of JRE is 64 bit on solaris Sparc

Tags: solaris, 32bit-64bit, java, sparc

Is there a clear or easy way to check over the command line if the installed JRE is 64 bit on a Sparc machine?

I am used to seeing this in:

```
java -version
```

however it appears that Solaris only says what version and build of java is installed.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Run `java -d64 -version`. It will complain if a 64 bit JVM isn't installed.

Comment: Thanks @jlliagre I ran a quick program that printed "sun.arch.data.model" and was continually getting 32, however when I ran the -d64 flag I received the the result of 64.  Will the machine know when to use 64 bit or will you always have to specify?

Comment: The machine cannot "know" when to use 64 bit, it is your choice when you start the JVM.

Comment: I am used to *nix machines automatically using the 64 bit JVM when its installed; I thought it was odd that the JVM in solaris runs 32 and 64 at the same time, but I guess that is why you have to specify. Thanks again

Answer (score -1):

If `d` ( in lower case) does not work, put `D` in Upper case.